# R Warning: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used. outer function

Tags: r, matrix, text, matching

I've got the following two functions:

```
name_fitting <- function(term1, term2)
  {
    if (nchar(term1) <= 3)
      {
       temp <- substring(term2, 1,nchar(term1))
       return(temp==term1)
      }
    else {return(grepl(term1, term2))}
  }

name_matching <- function(name1, name2)
  {
    name1 <- gsub('[[:punct:]]+','', name1)
    name2 <- gsub('[[:punct:]]+','', name2)
    if (length(intersect(as.character(unlist(strsplit(name1, ' '))), as.character(unlist(strsplit(name2, ' '))))) > 1) {return(TRUE)}
    if (length(intersect(as.character(unlist(strsplit(name1, ' '))), as.character(unlist(strsplit(name2, ' '))))) == 1) 
        {
          non_matching <- union(setdiff(as.character(unlist(strsplit(name1, ' '))), as.character(unlist(strsplit(name2, ' ')))), setdiff(as.character(unlist(strsplit(name2, ' '))), as.character(unlist(strsplit(name1, ' ')))))
          temp <- outer(X = non_matching, Y = non_matching, FUN = 'name_fitting')
          diag(temp)<-FALSE
          return(any(temp))
        }
    else(return(FALSE))
  }
```

name_fitting is used in name_matching. name_matching checks that the two names passed to the function are compatible and returns TRUE or FALSE.

When I try to match two names as follows:

```
name1<-"MARCO BRAMBILLA" 
name2<-"M BRAMBILLA BRANDUARDI"
```

I get the following warning:

> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Indicating that the outer function is not passing the data to name_fitting correctly.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something - why are you passing name_fitting the same argument twice?

Comment: Because This way I get a matrix of all the non matching terms against the name fitting function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function passes name_fitting the character vector `non_matching`, which contains three elements: `[1] "MARCO"      "M"          "BRANDUARDI"`. This vector is passed to the `if` call `if (nchar(term1) <= 3)`. The problem is that `nchar(term1) <= 3` gives a vector of length 3: `[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE`.

The question, of course, is what were you trying to achieve here. If you're trying to figure out if term1 has three or more elements, replace `nchar` with `length`. If you were trying to see if any of the elements of non_matching were 3 character long or less, place the nchar() call inside `any()`. If you were trying to check only the first element of non_matching, pass `term1[1]` instead of `term1`.

Comment: I thought that outer would have passes the elements of the vector: "non_matching" one by one as a product of arrays. Because that's what I was looking for.

Comment: From the documentation for outer: "FUN is called with these two extended vectors as arguments (plus any arguments in ...). It must be a vectorized function (or the name of one) expecting at least two arguments and returning a value with the same length as the first (and the second)."

Answer (score 1):

> Vectorize(function)

is the solution:

```
name_fitting <- function(term1, term2)
  {
    if (nchar(term1) <= 3)
      {
       temp <- substring(term2, 1,nchar(term1))
       return(temp==term1)
      }
    else {return(grepl(term1, term2))}
  }
name_fitting <- Vectorize(name_fitting)

name_matching <- function(name1, name2)
  {
    name1 <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:]]+','', name1))
    name2 <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:]]+','', name2))
    temp <- intersect(as.character(unlist(strsplit(name1, ' '))), as.character(unlist(strsplit(name2, ' '))))
    temp <- temp[temp!=c('')]
    if (length(temp) > 1) {return(TRUE)}
    if (length(intersect(as.character(unlist(strsplit(name1, ' '))), as.character(unlist(strsplit(name2, ' '))))) == 1) 
        {
          non_matching <- union(setdiff(as.character(unlist(strsplit(name1, ' '))), as.character(unlist(strsplit(name2, ' ')))), setdiff(as.character(unlist(strsplit(name2, ' '))), as.character(unlist(strsplit(name1, ' ')))))
          non_matching <- non_matching[non_matching!=c("")]
          temp <- outer(X = non_matching, Y = non_matching, FUN = 'name_fitting')
          diag(temp)<-FALSE
          return(any(temp))
        }
    else(return(FALSE))
  }

name_matching <- Vectorize(name_matching)
```